# pandas time interval to time series

Tags: python, pandas

How do i transform time interval data into time series data using Python (and pandas)?

Here's my before data frame as time intervals:

```
code    start_dt                    end_dt                      ent_value
156600  1960-01-01  2016-04-21  H:CXP
156600  1960-01-01  2016-01-03  46927
156600  1998-08-31  2016-01-03  5516751
156600  1960-01-01  1998-08-30  4501242
```

For each combination of code and ent_value, we want a row in the frame for each day within that combination's start and end date (so as a time series):

```
code    as_of_dt   ent_value
156600  1960-01-01 H:CXP
156600  1960-01-02 H:CXP
156600  1960-01-03 H:CXP
156600  1960-01-01 46927
156600  1960-01-02 46927
156600  1960-01-03 46927
156600  1960-01-01 5516751
156600  1960-01-02 5516751
156600  1960-01-03 5516751
...
156600  2016-01-01 H:CXP
156600  2016-01-02 H:CXP
156600  2016-01-03 H:CXP
156600  2016-01-01 46927
156600  2016-01-02 46927
156600  2016-01-03 46927
156600  2016-01-01 5516751
156600  2016-01-02 5516751
156600  2016-01-03 5516751
```

How do I do this in an efficient manner?

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution.

```
data = pd.read_csv(open('/tmp/test.tab', 'r'), sep='\t')
tmp = [(e.code, pd.date_range(e.start_dt, e.end_dt, freq='1D'), 
    e.ent_value) for e in data.itertuples()]
res = [(line[0], date, line[2]) for date in line[1] for line in tmp]
df = pd.DataFrame(res)`
```

The function `pd.date_range()` is used to create the dates ranges.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
In [17]: %paste
(df.groupby(['code','ent_value'])
   .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame({'as_of_dt':pd.date_range(x.start_dt.min(), x.end_dt.max())}))
   .reset_index()
   .drop('level_2', 1)
)
## -- End pasted text --
Out[17]:
         code ent_value   as_of_dt
0      156600   4501242 1960-01-01
1      156600   4501242 1960-01-02
2      156600   4501242 1960-01-03
3      156600   4501242 1960-01-04
4      156600   4501242 1960-01-05
5      156600   4501242 1960-01-06
6      156600   4501242 1960-01-07
7      156600   4501242 1960-01-08
8      156600   4501242 1960-01-09
9      156600   4501242 1960-01-10
10     156600   4501242 1960-01-11
11     156600   4501242 1960-01-12
12     156600   4501242 1960-01-13
13     156600   4501242 1960-01-14
14     156600   4501242 1960-01-15
15     156600   4501242 1960-01-16
16     156600   4501242 1960-01-17
17     156600   4501242 1960-01-18
18     156600   4501242 1960-01-19
19     156600   4501242 1960-01-20
20     156600   4501242 1960-01-21
21     156600   4501242 1960-01-22
22     156600   4501242 1960-01-23
23     156600   4501242 1960-01-24
24     156600   4501242 1960-01-25
25     156600   4501242 1960-01-26
26     156600   4501242 1960-01-27
27     156600   4501242 1960-01-28
28     156600   4501242 1960-01-29
29     156600   4501242 1960-01-30
...       ...       ...        ...
61450  156600     H:CXP 2016-03-23
61451  156600     H:CXP 2016-03-24
61452  156600     H:CXP 2016-03-25
61453  156600     H:CXP 2016-03-26
61454  156600     H:CXP 2016-03-27
61455  156600     H:CXP 2016-03-28
61456  156600     H:CXP 2016-03-29
61457  156600     H:CXP 2016-03-30
61458  156600     H:CXP 2016-03-31
61459  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-01
61460  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-02
61461  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-03
61462  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-04
61463  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-05
61464  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-06
61465  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-07
61466  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-08
61467  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-09
61468  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-10
61469  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-11
61470  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-12
61471  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-13
61472  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-14
61473  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-15
61474  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-16
61475  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-17
61476  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-18
61477  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-19
61478  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-20
61479  156600     H:CXP 2016-04-21

[61480 rows x 3 columns]
```

Test DF with smaller date ranges:

```
In [19]: df
Out[19]:
     code   start_dt     end_dt ent_value
0  156600 1960-01-01 1960-01-04     H:CXP
1  156600 1960-01-04 1960-01-09     46927
2  156600 1998-08-31 1998-09-04   5516751
3  156600 1965-01-01 1965-01-04   4501242

In [20]: (df.groupby(['code','ent_value'])
   ....:    .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame({'as_of_dt':pd.date_range(x.start_dt.min(), x.end_dt.max())}))
   ....:    .reset_index()
   ....:    .drop('level_2', 1)
   ....: )
Out[20]:
      code ent_value   as_of_dt
0   156600   4501242 1965-01-01
1   156600   4501242 1965-01-02
2   156600   4501242 1965-01-03
3   156600   4501242 1965-01-04
4   156600     46927 1960-01-04
5   156600     46927 1960-01-05
6   156600     46927 1960-01-06
7   156600     46927 1960-01-07
8   156600     46927 1960-01-08
9   156600     46927 1960-01-09
10  156600   5516751 1998-08-31
11  156600   5516751 1998-09-01
12  156600   5516751 1998-09-02
13  156600   5516751 1998-09-03
14  156600   5516751 1998-09-04
15  156600     H:CXP 1960-01-01
16  156600     H:CXP 1960-01-02
17  156600     H:CXP 1960-01-03
18  156600     H:CXP 1960-01-04
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the following DataFrame, called `df` (see below to check how to create it):

```
(see below to recreate this example)

    id  starttime   endtime     flag
0   A   2020-03-18  2020-03-20  y
1   B   2020-03-20  2020-03-23  n
2   C   2020-03-19  2020-03-21  y
```

Then, you can create the new dataframe, by iterating over all columns with the help of date_range:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = ((row.id, row.flag, date)
                # iterate over rows
                for row in df.itertuples()
                # expad the range into 1 day intervals
                for date in pd.date_range(row.starttime, row.endtime, freq='1D')),
    columns = ['name', 'flag', 'interval']))
```

You will end with this:

```
name    flag    interval
0   A   y   2020-03-18
1   A   y   2020-03-19
2   A   y   2020-03-20
3   B   n   2020-03-20
4   B   n   2020-03-21
5   B   n   2020-03-22
6   B   n   2020-03-23
7   C   y   2020-03-19
8   C   y   2020-03-20
9   C   y   2020-03-21
```

---

## Recreate the data example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'starttime': ['2020-03-18', '2020-03-20','2020-03-19' ],
    'endtime': ['2020-03-20', '2020-03-23','2020-03-21'],
    'flag': ['y','n','y']
})

df['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['starttime'])
df['endtime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['endtime'])
```