# DateTime range into "long format" with exact 15 minutes ("o'clock quarters") intervals with duration?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Suppose I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
(see code below to re-create this example)

    user    starttime   endtime     flag
0   Alice   2020-03-20 15:05:00     2020-03-20 15:36:00     y
1   Bob     2020-03-20 15:16:00     2020-03-20 15:40:00     m
2   Chap    2020-03-20 15:00:00     2020-03-20 15:30:00     y
3   Dana    2020-03-20 20:05:00     2020-03-20 20:44:00     y
```

I want to split each time range (i.e. between `starttime` and `endtime`) into 15 minutes slots (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678955/pandas-time-interval-to-time-series/63953519#63953519)), but I want exact 15 minutes slots (i.e. "o'clock quarters", e.g. 15:00, 15:15) and the duration corresponding to each of this quarters.

Basically, the data will look like this:

```
    name    flag    quarter                 duration
0   Alice   y       2020-03-20 15:00:00     00:10:00
1   Alice   y       2020-03-20 15:15:00     00:15:00
2   Alice   y       2020-03-20 15:30:00     00:05:00
3   Bob     m       2020-03-20 15:15:00     00:14:00
4   Bob     m       2020-03-20 15:30:00     00:01:00
5   Chap    y       2020-03-20 15:00:00     00:15:00
6   Chap    y       2020-03-20 15:15:00     00:15:00
7   Chap    y       2020-03-20 15:30:00     00:00:00
8   Dana    y       2020-03-20 20:00:00     00:10:00
9   Dana    y       2020-03-20 20:15:00     00:15:00
10  Dana    y       2020-03-20 20:30:00     00:05:00
```

In case you are wondering ***what for***: I have another dataframe with different prices associated to the "o'clock prices", therefore, I need to calculate duration in each of the quarters before I merge the data.

---

### Code to re-create example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Chap', 'Dana'],
    'starttime': ['2020-03-20 15:05:00', '2020-03-20 15:16:00','2020-03-20 15:00:00', '2020-03-20 20:05:00' ],
    'endtime': ['2020-03-20 15:36:00', '2020-03-20 15:40:00','2020-03-20 15:30:00', '2020-03-20 20:44:00'],
    'flag': ['y','m','y', 'y']
})

df['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['starttime'])
df['endtime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['endtime'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with my own solution,:

```
# Split into quarters
new = pd.DataFrame(((
                        e.name, 
                        e.flag, 
                        # for the first interval use the starttime
                        e.starttime if date == e.starttime.floor('15min') else date,
                        # for the last interval use the endtime
                        e.endtime if date == e.endtime.floor('15min') else date + pd.Timedelta(minutes=15)
                    )    
                    #iterate over thet uples
                    for e  in df.itertuples()
                    # iterate for each range date
                    for date in pd.date_range(e.starttime.floor('15min'), e.endtime.floor('15min'), freq='15min')
                ), columns = ['name', 'flag', 'start', 'end'])

# calculate the duration
new['duration'] = new['end']- new['start']
```

However, it is not exactly elegant, and I need to fix a lot of details along the way that might be source of errors. This seems to be quite a typical use case, so I am sure there should be better solutions out there.

#### Final result

My final dataset looks like this. I could reuse some of the columns, but I think it is clear this way to reflect the amount of steps taken to get to this solution.

```
    name   flag start                   end                     duration
0   Alice   y   2020-03-20 15:05:00     2020-03-20 15:15:00     00:10:00
1   Alice   y   2020-03-20 15:15:00     2020-03-20 15:30:00     00:15:00
2   Alice   y   2020-03-20 15:30:00     2020-03-20 15:41:00     00:11:00
3   Bob     m   2020-03-20 15:16:00     2020-03-20 15:30:00     00:14:00
4   Bob     m   2020-03-20 15:30:00     2020-03-20 15:40:00     00:10:00
5   Chap    y   2019-03-20 12:58:00     2019-03-20 13:00:00     00:02:00
6   Chap    y   2019-03-20 13:00:00     2019-03-20 13:15:00     00:15:00
7   Chap    y   2019-03-20 13:15:00     2019-03-20 13:30:00     00:15:00
8   Chap    y   2019-03-20 13:30:00     2019-03-20 13:41:00     00:11:00
9   Dana    y   2020-03-20 20:05:00     2020-03-20 20:15:00     00:10:00
10  Dana    y   2020-03-20 20:15:00     2020-03-20 20:30:00     00:15:00
11  Dana    y   2020-03-20 20:30:00     2020-03-20 20:44:00     00:14:00
```